# Start remote non-delphi service from delphi application

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I have an application which is exposing a background service which I wish to start and comunicate with. Anyway TRemoteServiceConnection does not have a method to start such service.

- How to start remote service which is part of another application (native java code) from delphi application ?

Comment: The remote service should start automatically when you bind to it with `TRemoteServiceConnection`. See [Bound services overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services). If you are having trouble, please show your actual code.

Comment: Not sure who decided that this is duplicate, but he definitely missed to even read the question.